# Issue in Parsing JSON object from CoreData

Tags: ios, json, swift, core-data

I converted a JSON object to string and stored it to CoreData. But how to parse the individual elements and get each of the elements after retrieving the JSON object that I'm not able to figure out....

This is how I'm getting the `json` object:

```
let mobileNumber = mobileNumberTextfield.text
let firstName = firstNameTextField.text

let jsonObject: [String: [String:Any]] = [
    "user1": [
        "mobile_number": mobileNumber,
        "first_Name": firstName,
    ]
]
```

I'm printing JSON string like so...

```
if let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonObject, options: .prettyPrinted),
    let str = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
    print(str)
}
```

printing `str` gives:

```
{
  "user1" : {
    "mobile_number" : "567567567",
    "first_Name" : "iopiopi",
  }
}
```

I'm storing it as it is to `coredata` and so when I retrive it I get it back in the very same format as above. But how can I retrieve the individual elements for later use that I can't figure out.

If I fetch it something like so...

```
for result in  newProductDetails {
    if let prodID = result.value(forKey: "address") as? String {
        print(prodID)

    }
}
```

and do a `for (key, value) in addDetails.enumerated()` & print value, it give this..

```
 data: {
    address = "{
\n  \"user1\" : {
\n    \"mobile_number\" : \"1236594525\",
\n    \"first_Name\" : \"ghj\"
\n  
}
\n
}";
})
```

But how can I extract individual values of `mobile_number` & `first_Name`from it ...?

Answer (score 2):

You are storing the data (`NSData` obtained from the string encoding the JSON) and getting back that same data from CoreData. That means you have to parse the JSON in that `NSData` instance again. The round trip to JSON/NSData and back makes little sense. You probably just want to create an User entity and store the mobile number and first name into CoreData directly.

Comment: you are right @Johan Kool. That of course is recommended also. But in my project scenario, I want to store a some data as json object into coredata. That's why I'm looking at this approach. Hope u can help...:)

Comment: as Johan said, its best to store each piece of data in its own field. Or you will be doing more work to read the data and will not be able to search the data in core data by these fields. if you really must store it this way, you need to convert that JSON string back into a dictionary or model object and then you can access the values

Answer (score 2):

**Convert Json string to Dictionary:**

```
func convertToDictionary(text: String) -> [String: Any]? {

    if let data = text.data(using: .utf8) {

         do {

             return try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any]
          } catch {
             print(error.localizedDescription)
          }
    }
    return nil
}

let str = "{\"name\":\"James\"}"

let dict = convertToDictionary(text: str)
```

You should save like this in CoreData:

```
          if let reposArray: AnyObject = json["user1"] as? NSDictionary {

                self.mbleNo = reposArray["mobile_number"] as? String
                let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
                if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                    let managedObjectContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
                    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Fields")
                    let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Fields", in:managedObjectContext)
                    let titleInfo = NSManagedObject(entity: entityDescription!, insertInto: managedObjectContext) as? Fields
                    titleInfo?.setValue(self.mbleNo, forKey: "mobile_number")

                    do {

                        try titleInfo?.managedObjectContext?.save()
                    }
                    catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
                 }
            }
```

Comment: But @Suganya Marlin I have already saved into coredata and when I retrieve, I get this... `{
  "user1" : {
    "mobile_number" : "567567567",
    "first_Name" : "iopiopi",
  }
}` But how to extract data from these that I can't figure out....

Comment: Use the above code to save..then u can retrieve it easily...This is the proper way  of saving elements in CoreData

Comment: u r right . But in my project scenario, I have to do it the other way...:) In @Scriptable's words above,  "....if you really must store it this way, you need to convert that JSON string back into a dictionary or model object and then you can access the values.."
      You have any idea regarding this...?

Comment: I have given the code to convert string to json object

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164752/discussion-between-suganya-marlin-and-v-bw).